# how to customize Verify behavior in django-graphql-jwt

Tags: django, graphql

I want to customize the `Verify` behavior in [django-graphql-jwt](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/blob/9879f29a2a9de421b11e6bf04f9c55b2f2d97dd7/graphql_jwt/mutations.py#L43).

the only thing I found in the documentation is [customizing](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/stable/customizing.html) the `ObtainJSONWebToken` behavior.

how I can override this class correctly?

Comment: here is an example of overriding this class: https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth/blob/07012f2e7875ee017b0eb4887506293ec5e5572c/graphql_auth/mutations.py#L140

Comment: comment above does not really explain much